# Wants to change Existing Opencart database Password format

Tags: php, mysql, sql, opencart

I am maintaining Opencart website. Now I am going to update oc_customers table.

I want to convert existing customer's password  (md5+salt) to simple password format.

I don't want to use too complicate format. I want to maintain Password simply as like as base64_encode($testPassword); For New customer thats not a problem.

But For the Existing Customers, I don't know how to change md5+salt -> normal -> base64_encode?

Comment: Show us some code, what have you tried? How did those attempts fail?

Comment: I don't want to use too complicate format. I want to maintain 
Password simply as like as base64_encode($testPassword);
For New customer thats no pblm. But For the Existing Customers,
I don't know how to change md5+salt -> normal -> base64_encode?

Comment: Password format (md5+salt) maintaining is easier than the converting   like as md5+salt -> normal -> base64_encode.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, this is a bad idea since password salting is an important and pretty standard operation when storing passwords. The main thing it accomplishes is protect your users in the case a malicious third party gains access to your database. In the event that happens, the attacker will have to brute force every single password separately which slows the attack down and prevents the attacker from using a precomputed rainbow table.

If you REALLY wanted to do this, then you'll have to support both authentication methods and add a flag which method each customer is using, then when you get a successful login from a customer using the old method, you have access to the correct plain text password which you can record in the new format. With salting it is difficult for an attacker to deduce the original password, and for the same reason it is difficult for you to convert them to the new format without knowing the password. Salting prevents the website owner from knowing what the actual password is, which is a desirable feature.

Lastly, using base64 is practically the same as just storing the password as plain text, since anyone can just decode the base64_encode'd string. Hash functions are better since you can't just reverse them like base64, but still have the issue that people can just precompute a large number of hashes. And that's why you want to use salting.